# Error saving data using Entity Framework: System.InvalidOperationException: 'This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to save data to my SQL Server database using Entity Framework, but the following error occurs:

> System.InvalidOperationException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

I have read that this exception must be generated because it detects that it is a zombie attack because there are many requests.

I use postman to send the data but here there is no problem because I see when using the debugger that the information arrives. The postman code is as follows:

```
[
     {
         "tag":"234567",
         "idDepartment":"4",
         "idCostCenter":"4",
         "idCustomer":"9"
     }
]
```

The following code is where the error occurs:

```
public JsonResult UpdateDataDrivers([FromBody] List<Driver> oData)
{
    AgregaLog("Entro al metodo UpdateDataDrivers", "UpdateDataDrivers");

    using var dbtfcontext = new TankfarmContext();
    using var dbtftransaction = dbtfcontext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    using var dbws1context = new Ws1Context();
    using var dbws1transaction = dbws1context.Database.BeginTransaction();

    Int32 maxIdws1 = 1 + (from data in dbws1context.ClientesChoferes where data.Codcli == 3 select data.Nrocho).Max();
    bool error = false;

    try
    {
        foreach (var item in oData)
        {
            var chofere1 = dbtfcontext.Choferes.First(a => a.Tag == item.tag);
            var clientesChoferes1 = dbws1context.ClientesChoferes.First(a => a.Tag == item.tag);

            if (chofere1 != null)
            {
                chofere1.IdCliente = Int32.Parse(item.idCliente);
                chofere1.CentroCostos = item.idCentroCostos.ToString();
                chofere1.Departamento = item.idDepartamento.ToString();
                chofere1.Status = "1";

                if (clientesChoferes1 != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Encontro registros por lo que debe actualizar");
                    int nrochotemporal = clientesChoferes1.Nrocho;

                    dbws1context.Remove(clientesChoferes1);
                    dbws1context.SaveChanges();
                    dbws1transaction.Commit();

                    var clientesChoferes = new ClientesChofere
                            {
                                Codcli = Int32.Parse(item.idCliente),
                                Nrocho = nrochotemporal,
                                Den = chofere1.NameComplete,
                                Diacar = 127,
                                Hraini = 0,
                                Hrafin = 2359,
                                Tag = chofere1.Tag,
                                Codest = 0,
                                Logusu = 0,
                                Logfch = DateTime.Today
                            };
                    dbws1context.ClientesChoferes.Add(clientesChoferes);                         
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No encontro registros por lo que debe insertar");

                    var clientesChoferes = new ClientesChofere
                            {
                                Codcli = Int32.Parse(item.idCliente),
                                Nrocho = maxIdws1,
                                Den = chofere1.NameComplete,
                                Diacar = 127,
                                Hraini = 0,
                                Hrafin = 2359,
                                Tag = chofere1.Tag,
                                Codest = 0,
                                Logusu = 0,
                                Logfch = DateTime.Today
                            };
                    dbws1context.ClientesChoferes.Add(clientesChoferes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mensajes.Status = "Fail";
                mensajes.StatusMensaje = "No se encontro el usuario";
            }

            maxIdws1++;
        }

        dbws1context.SaveChanges();
        dbtfcontext.SaveChanges();

        dbtftransaction.Commit();
        dbws1transaction.Commit();

        AgregaLog("Agrega a UpdateDataDrivers", "UpdateDataDrivers");
        mensajes.Status = "ok";
        mensajes.StatusMensaje = "Regresando datos";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tipo de excepción de reversión: {0}", e.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Mensaje: {0}", e.Message);
        AgregaLog("Error al terminar WS UpdateDataDrivers" + e.Message, "UpdateDataDrivers");
        mensajes.Status = "Error";
        mensajes.StatusMensaje = "Error al terminar WS UpdateDataDrivers" + e.Message;
        error = true;
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    if (error)
    {
        dbtftransaction.Rollback();
        dbws1transaction.Rollback();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("message.Status:" + mensajes.Status);
    Console.WriteLine("message.StatusMensaje:" + mensajes.StatusMensaje);

    return Json(mensajes);
}
```

Specifically in the part where you commit the transaction in the tankfarm database in the following line:

```
dbws1transaction.Commit();
```

And throws the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.'

The following files are the classes used to make the code work:

```
public partial class Chofere
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Nombre { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? SecondLastName { get; set; }
    public string? Telefono { get; set; }
    public int? IdCliente { get; set; }
    public int? IdIdioma { get; set; }
    public string? Gerente { get; set; }
    public string? Departamento { get; set; }
    public string? CentroCostos { get; set; }
    public string? Perfil { get; set; }
    public string? Correo { get; set; }
    public string? Tag { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public string? NameComplete { get; set; }
    public string? G_FROM_DATE { get; set; }
    public string? G_TO_DATE { get; set; }
    public string? G_RIGHTS { get; set; }
    public string? G_DESCRIPTIONSTATUS { get; set; }
}

public class ClientesChofere
{
    public int Codcli { get; set; }
    public int Nrocho { get; set; }
    public string? Den { get; set; }
    public short? Diacar { get; set; }
    public short? Hraini { get; set; }
    public short? Hrafin { get; set; }
    public string? Tag { get; set; }
    public int? Codest { get; set; }
    public int? Logusu { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Logfch { get; set; }
}

public class Mensajes
{
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string StatusMensaje { get; set; }
    public string ErroresUsuarios { get; set; }
    public string ErroresEliminacion { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more information I will be attentive to document more information

Comment: You have a double commit:
`dbws1context.Remove(clientesChoferes1);
 dbws1context.SaveChanges();
 dbws1transaction.Commit();`

Across all conditional paths there should only ever be one Commit or one Rollback.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the use of commits and rollbacks especially since I'm new to ASP.NET I'm going to remove the commit inside the conditional and then I'll tell you thanks.

Comment: I would like to ask you a question because in this line "if (driver1 != null)" I need to do a deletion from the database if the conditional is true but because a field is part of a compound key it marks an error and when modifying it too It marks an error, so my solution was to simply delete it and then save another record with the same data. My question is, will it work if I do the deletion inside another function?

Comment: If the DbContext is shared between the two functions (I.e. at a module level) which it looks like it is based on your previous code, then it should be fine. Yes, you cannot alter PK values in an entity so if you have something like a ClientDriver with a ClientId and DriverId forming the PK you need to remove the old linking record and replace it with a new linking record for the Client and new Driver.

Comment: Thanks Steve Py your comments helped me solve my problem thanks